How to pass list of args to variadic macro
I have a macro (I've simplified everything a lot):
(defmacro m1 [error & messages]
  `(if ~error
     (str "Error: " ~@messages)
     (str ~@messages)))

It works pretty well. But now I want to reuse it in a function with args [& messages]:
If I define this function the following way:
(defn error [& messages]
  (m1 true messages))

It works, but incorrectly of course. If I call (error "msg") it returns "Error: (\"msg\")"
But if I do something like:
(defn error [& messages]
  (apply m1 true messages))

It causes an error
; Syntax error compiling at ....
; Can't take value of a macro
So the question is how to pass messages list to variadic macro?

You cannot. Macros operate at macro expansion time, and there, messages is just a symbol.
m1 doesn't need to be a macro at all - it can be a plain function. And whenever you can use a function instead of a macro, you should most definitely do so to avoid any similar issues.

I know that such macro should be a plain function, I am just trying to understand how it works
Now it seems I got the idea. Thanks!

Maybe it's not what you are looking for but one option is to provide multiple arities to your function instead of using apply:
(defmacro m1 [error & messages]
  `(if ~error
     (str "Error: " ~@messages)
     (str ~@messages)))

(defn error
  ([b & messages] (m1 b messages))
  ([messages] (m1 true messages)))

